# How to search HTML table data of ''input type text'' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to **SEARCH** table data. My table `td` consists of textboxes.
**The code for searching works when I directly add data in `td's` but does not when my data is a value in textbox.** I've have done some coding for searching but it doesn't seem to work.
I just want to be able to search below table on input in a search box.
Screenshot of my table and code is given below :

[image: My table look like this]

products.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#search").keyup(
                    function () 
                    {
                        var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
                        $("table tr").each(
                            function (index) 
                            {
                                if (!index) return;
                                $(this).find("td").children().attr("value").each(
                                     function () 
                                     {
                                         var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                                         var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
                                         $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
                                         return not_found;
                                     });
                            });
                    }); 
        });
    </script>

   <!-- Fetch table data -->
   <sql:setDataSource var="myDataSource" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.56.49:1521:something" user="something" password="something"/>
   <sql:query var="result" sql="select * from garageproducts" dataSource="${myDataSource}"/>

    <table id="mytable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Mark</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%! int cnt=0; %>
                <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                  <tr>
                    <td hidden="true">${row.pid}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id='<%= "barcode"+cnt %>' value="${row.barcode}" name="barcodename" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id='<%= "name"+cnt %>' value="${row.name}" name="namename" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id='<%= "brand"+cnt %>' value="${row.brand}" name="brandname" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id='<%= "stock"+cnt %>' value="${row.stock}" name="stockname" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id='<%= "cost"+cnt %>' value="${row.cost}" name="costname" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <% ++cnt; %>
                </c:forEach>

            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what is the use of return not_found;?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the selector `$('input[type="text"]')`? You can also look use an ID: `$('#input-id[type="text"]')`. You are specifying an element with the attribute `type` that has the value `text` with `[type="text"]`.

Comment: you can set an input to readonly false, that way you will be able to edit it, you can set it to disabled after edit should you wish. js: document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = false; jquery $("#myText").prop("readonly", false);

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Can you give me jquery code for searching the above html table

Comment: @madalinivascu return not_found will return false when the data is not found and the searching will stop

Comment: Instead of using ```.attr("value")``` you need to filter by attribute. If you use ```attr()``` then you lose the reference to the element and the following code will not work as you expect (if at all). Also consider using the developer console to look at JavaScript error messages.

Comment: @RachelGallen Sorry ive edited my question little. I dont want to sort, I just want to search from table containing textboxes.

Comment: @prthmshjadv you could use something like this: `$('#mytable>tbody td>input[type="text"]').each(..)`

Comment: @NicholasRobinson I tried doing the following `$(this).find('#mytable>tbody td>input[type="text"]').each(...)`
Does't seem to work :(

Comment: @prthmshjadv Is that on the line following: `if (!index) return;`?

Comment: If so, `this` is refering to the "table tr" elements. Calling `$(this).find(..)` is going to search the children of whatever `this` is. So in this case you will need to call `$(this).find('td>input[type="text"]').each(...)`

Comment: jQuery selectors are the same as CSS selectors. Here is a good table to reference when building a selector (Just remember that if you are using `$('#something).fund()` you will only be looking at the children of `#something`) - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Using `$(this).find('td>input[type="text"]').each(...)` I have reference to the input element(which is  child for each tr). But further how can I search and show only the rows which match the search string?
Now when I search, no matching rows are displayed.

Comment: @prthmshjadv: for this you can use `.filter()` http://api.jquery.com/filter/ .. The filter function iterated though each element and returns true if the element should be kept and false otherwise. So you can use something like: `$(this).find('td>input[type="text"]').filter(function (index) { return $(this).val() === searchString; })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118885/discussion-between-prthmsh-jadv-and-nicholas-robinson).

Answer (score 0):

I partially found a solution. The search is working but it does not work as expected. It hides the cells which do not match the search string.

Following is the fiddle link for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/freecoder/hfhtga0g/6/

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#search").keyup(function() {
                _this = this;
                // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
                $.each($('#mytable tbody tr td>input[type="text"]'), function() {
                  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                    $(this).hide();
                  else
                    $(this).show();
                });
              });
            });

    </script>

    <html>
      <label for="search">Search products :</label>
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter text to search">

      <!-- Fetch table data -->
       <sql:setDataSource var="myDataSource" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.56.49:1521:something" user="something" password="something"/>
       <sql:query var="result" sql="select * from garageproducts" dataSource="${myDataSource}"/>

            <table id="mytable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Mark</th>
                        <th>Barcode</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                          <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox">                    </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.barcode}"> </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.name}">    </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.brand}">   </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.stock}">   </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.cost}">    </td>
                          </tr>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
    </html>
```